# Newton's method of finding square root in python using only while loop

Tags: python

The loop is not running at all.
I'm just new to python and I have no idea what I did wrong.

```
x = float(input("Enter a number: "))
y = x * 0.5
while True:
    y = 0.5 * (y + (x/y))
    y_square = y * y
    if -0.001 < y_square < 0.001:
        break
print("Square root:",y_square)
```

Comment: The loop is running and it is running infinitely.
Try printing inside the loop and you'll see it is running infinitely
your if condition that breaks you out of loop isn't working in this case.

Comment: Such small programs can be easily debugged using [PythonTutor](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit).

Answer (score 1):

Your loop *does* run, but it never stops.

Two issues:

- `if -0.001 < y_square < 0.001`: surely you don't expect the square to be that small? It needs to be *close to `x`*, not close to zero. So change that to:

  ```
  if -0.001 < y_square - x < 0.001:
  ```
- The output should not be about `y_square`. You are not interested in the square, since that is what the user provided. You want to output the root, which is `y`:

  ```
  print("Square root:", y)
  ```